# When POST, Spring is ignoring @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot for creating a REST service but I'm having some problems with underscore attributes. In my model I have an attribute that is called `publicId` and I'm using `@JsonProperty` to have the json value `public_id`. It works perfectly for serialization, when I request some GET resource, it returns with underscore like expected, but when I'm trying to POST some new object with `public_id` it doesn't recognize, only if I send the POST data as `publicId`.

Model example:

```
@Entity
public class Foo{

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @JsonProperty(value = "public_id")
    private String publicId;

    //...//
}
```

Controller example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object createFoo(Foo foo,
                            HttpServletRequest request) {
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Because that isn't using JSON but normal parameter binding. Either send JSON and annotate the method parameter with `@RequestBody` or use binding and don't send `public_id` as a parameter but `publicId`. finding request parameters and (de)serializing JSON are different beasts.

Comment: The binding as that is plain parameter binding...

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, just tested here and worked just fine by using `@RequestBody` and sending raw with Content-Type application/json (using postman). But what can I do when I have to upload a file with it? Because it have to be a multipart request..